# Flutter: how to fix bottom overflow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Flutter Widget with a column layout that has two Containers, one of which has a `ListView.builder`. When the page renders I get a

> bottom overflow by 169px

and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've googled around for solutions and have tried various things like wrapping one or more of the `Container`s in the widget in an `Expanded` widget, but that doesn't work either. If I wrap just the `Container` that has the `FutureBuilder` inside of it in an `Expanded`, then the `ListView` doesn't render at all and I see errors like:

```
I/flutter ( 3516): Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter ( 3516): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#0caf9 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3516): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#963f4 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3516): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
```

This is what the build function of my Widget looks like:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0),
              child: TextField(
                  autofocus: false,
                  controller: searchFilterController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
                      hintText: 'Search',
                      suffixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    filter = value;
                  }))),

      Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<UserPantry>(
        future: UserPantryDao.getUserPantry(widget.userId),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            widget.ingredientList.clear();
            if (filter == null || filter.trim() == "") {
              widget.ingredientList.addAll(snapshot.data.ingredients);
            } else {
              for (UserIngredient ingredient in snapshot.data.ingredients) {
                if (ingredient.ingredient.name
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(filter.toLowerCase())) {
                  widget.ingredientList.add(ingredient);
                }
              }
            }

            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: widget.ingredientList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                    widget.ingredientList[index].ingredient.name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ));
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print(snapshot.error);
            return Text(
                "An error occurred while loading your pantry. Please try again.");
          }
          //By default just show an empty container.
          return Container();
        },
      ))
    ]));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try remove the `Container` outside, and wrap the list in a expanded.
As @Miguel Ruivo answered, ListView must have a bounded constraints.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 2.0, 10.0, 2.0),
              child: TextField(
                  autofocus: false,
                  controller: searchFilterController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
                      hintText: 'Search',
                      suffixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    filter = value;
                  }))),
      Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder<UserPantry>(
        future: UserPantryDao.getUserPantry(widget.userId),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            widget.ingredientList.clear();
            if (filter == null || filter.trim() == "") {
              widget.ingredientList.addAll(snapshot.data.ingredients);
            } else {
              for (UserIngredient ingredient in snapshot.data.ingredients) {
                if (ingredient.ingredient.name
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(filter.toLowerCase())) {
                  widget.ingredientList.add(ingredient);
                }
              }
            }

            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: widget.ingredientList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                    widget.ingredientList[index].ingredient.name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ));
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print(snapshot.error);
            return Text(
                "An error occurred while loading your pantry. Please try again.");
          }
          //By default just show an empty container.
          return Container();
        },
      ))
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply Wrap the `List` only with `Expanded`.
Try this:

```
Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text("data"),
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
              Expanded(child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return Text("data");
              })),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `FutureBuilder<UserPantry>` in an `Expanded` widget and remove the `Container` because you don't need it at all here.

```
 Expanded(
        child: FutureBuilder<UserPantry>(
           future: UserPantryDao.getUserPantry(widget.userId),
   ...
```

This happens because you're giving unbounded constraints to the `ListView`. Another option, would be adding some `height` constraint to the `ListView` parent, such as setting the `height` in the `Container` to something.

Comment: That was one of the things I tried already, but when I do that the whole page is blank and I see these errors in the console: 
I/flutter ( 5471): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#350b4 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 5471): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#3fe57 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 5471): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.

Comment: I don’t have your whole tree. As you’ve it right now, it should work. Anyway, just set some height to the `Container` and you should be fine.

Comment: Setting a height on the container does resolve the issue, but how will I know what height to use? Won't it vary from device to device?

Comment: Yes, but you can use a %, by doing `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5`, this will set your `ListView` to use 50% of the screen height. However, with `Expanded` you shouldn't need this, and it should work as well, because you'll expand to fill the viewport vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `ListView.separated( separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(), ...)` in `Expanded`  will solve your issue.

Eg: `Expanded(child: ListView.separated(separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>Divider(),itemCount: 1, itemBuilder: (context, index) {return Container(height:200.0, child: ...);})`